# Forms abertos alteram tamanho ao fechar outro

Tags: delphi

Tenho `forms` do tipo `fsMDIChild` que estão definidos para inicialiar maximizados (`wsMaximized`). Eles abrem normalmente, entretanto quando eu fecho algum deles os demais alteram seu estado para `WsNormal`.

Gostaria de saber se tem como evitar isso, mesmo que seja forçando para que o tamanho não altere.

Código de inserção dos forms:

```
  if not Assigned(frmfornecedor) then
  begin
     frmfornecedor := tfrmfornecedor.create(frmPrincipal);
  end;
```

No evento `OnClose` dos forms apenas existe um `Close` e nada mais.

Comment: Eu não consegui reproduzir esse problema aqui. Esses formulários são criados em *runtime*?

Comment: Sim amigo, são runtime

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta e colocar como você está criando esses forms?

Comment: Adicionei, veja se isso ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso deve ter sido causado devido á alguma alteração nas propriedades do formulário `FrmFornecedor` pois não consegui reproduzir esse problema, verifique se a propriedade `AutoSize` está marcada como *False*.

No evento `OnClose()` do formulário `FrmFornecedor` ao invés de usar `Close`, use:

```
procedure TFrmFornecedor.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
Action := caFree;
end;
```

Comment: O problema era no evento FormClose mesmo, entretanto além do Action := caFree eu acrescentei o frmfornecedor := nil;
Muito obrigado amigo, isso resolveu meu problema :D